Halachic sources against placing tefillin on non-religious Jews
Please provide halachic sources (responsum, articles, video or podcasts) which broadly take the stance that it is prohibited for an orthodox Jew to compel a non-religious Jew to don tefillin outside of a broader context of accepting Judaism more generally.
Put another way, are there poskim who reject the ongoing Chabad practice of encouraging non-religious Jews to wear tefillin, and if so what is their reasoning?

Compel? Last I checked they don't use force

According to Rosh HaShannah 17a as explained by Rav (it seems the Gemara does not object to Rav's conclusion), it would seem wierd for the Talmud to hold that a Jew who did not put on Tefillin (and had other aveiros) on the one hand is designated as a major sinner, yet at the same time the Halachah would hold that we should not let the fellow rectify the issue by not allowing us to offer him Tefillin? How can he be held liable for missing Tefillin if he is not allowed to wear them?

@DavidKenner that is not a halachic argument

@DavidKenner That's like me voluntarily spending the whole day in the bathroom and claiming "oops I couldn't say shema, daven, etc."

It’s not usur to offer a person the option to do teshuva. Those who initially opposed it, such as other chasidim and the Reform movement, did so for social reasons, l’choira. For context, look at the machlokes between the Rabbeinu Tam and Rashi regarding tefillin themselves. It was a centuries ago, and that machlokes, regarding the actual composition of tefillin, is still unresolved.
